# 2 acciones por una misma sentencia <a>

Tags: php, pdo

¿Alguien sabe como colocar este codigo correctamente?
Estoy siguiendo uno del foro que encontrado pero siempre me indica:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: 
> number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
> ```

```
<a href="index2.php?action=editar&id="<?php echo $r->acro_documento; ?>
<?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" 
height="30px"/>
```

codigo

index.php

```
// Logica
$alm = new Categoria();
$model = new CategoriaModel();

if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
    case 'actualizar':



        // Recupero el id del campo hidden

        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $_REQUEST['acro_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $_REQUEST['acro_subcategoria']);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $_REQUEST['tipo_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $_REQUEST['registro_calidad']);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $_REQUEST['calidad_code']);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $_REQUEST['cod_tempo']);

        $update_results = $model->Actualizar($alm, $_POST['id']);

        header('Location: index2.php');

        break;

    case 'registrar':
        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $_REQUEST['acro_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $_REQUEST['acro_subcategoria']);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $_REQUEST['tipo_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $_REQUEST['registro_calidad']);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $_REQUEST['calidad_code']);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $_REQUEST['cod_tempo']);

        $model->Registrar($alm);
        header('Location: index2.php');
        break;

    case 'eliminar':
        $model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['acro_documento']);
        $model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['acro_subcategoria']);
        header('Location: index2.php');
        break;

    case 'editar':
        // Recupero los datos por el id
        // $obj_categoria es un objeto del tipo Categoria
        $obj_categoria = $model->Obtener($_REQUEST['id']);

        break;
    default:
        // MENSAJE 404 PARA CUANDO LA ACCION NO ES VALIDA
        header('HTTP/1.0: 404 Not Found');
        die('<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>');
}
}
?>
```

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">
</head>
<body style="padding:15px;">

    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1-12">

            <form action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_documento'): ''; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_subcategoria'): ''; ?>" />

                <table style="width:500px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Documento</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="acro_documento"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Subcategoria</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="acro_subcategoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_subcategoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Tipo de Documento</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tipo_documento"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('tipo_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Registro de Calidad</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="registro_calidad"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('registro_calidad') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Calidad Code</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="calidad_code"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('calidad_code') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo de Tiempo</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cod_tempo"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('cod_tempo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

            <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Documento</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Subcategoria</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Tipo de Documento</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Registro de Calidad</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Calidad Code</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo de tiempo</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Edicion</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Eliminar</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php foreach ($model->Listar() as $r): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('acro_documento'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('acro_subcategoria'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('tipo_documento'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('registro_calidad'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('calidad_code'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('cod_tempo'); ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo $r->acro_documento;?>"
                               href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>"
                            >
                            <img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=eliminar&acro_documento=<?php echo $r->acro_documento; ?>"
                               href="?action=eliminar&acro_subcategoria=<?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>"
                            >
                            <img src="delete.png" width="30px" height=30px"/></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

alumno.model2.php

```
<?php

class CategoriaModel {

private $pdo;

public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Listar() {
    try {
        $result = array();

        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipodocumentos");
        $stm->execute();

        foreach ($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $r) {
            $alm = new Categoria();

            $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $r->acro_documento);
            $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $r->acro_subcategoria);
            $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $r->tipo_documento);
            $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $r->registro_calidad);
            $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $r->calidad_code);
            $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $r->cod_tempo);
            $result[] = $alm;
        }

        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Obtener($acronimo) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento  = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
        $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $alm = new Categoria();

        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $r->acro_documento);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $r->acro_subcategoria);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $r->tipo_documento);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $r->registro_calidad);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $r->calidad_code);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $r->cod_tempo);

        return $alm;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Eliminar($acronimo) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo
                ->prepare("DELETE FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// ##############################################################################################
// CAMBIOS REALIZADOS
// - USO DE PARAMETROS NOMBRADOS EN EN METODO .execute()
// ##############################################################################################       
public function Actualizar(Categoria $data, $acro_doc_viejo, $acro_sub_viejo) {

    try {

        $sql = "UPDATE tipodocumentos SET tipo_documento =:tipo_documento, registro_calidad =:registro_calidad, calidad_code =:calidad_code, "
                . "cod_tempo =:cod_tempo, acro_documento =:acro_documento, acro_subcategoria =:acro_subcategoria WHERE acro_documento=:acro_doc_viejo and acro_subcategoria =:acro_sub_viejo";



        return $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
                        ->execute(
                                array(
                                    ':acro_doc_viejo' => $acro_doc_viejo,
                                    ':acro_sub_viejo' => $acro_sub_viejo,
                                    ':acro_documento' => $data->__GET('acro_documento'),
                                    ':acro_subcategoria' => $data->__GET('acro_subcategoria'),
                                    ':tipo_documento' => $data->__GET('tipo_documento'),
                                    ':registro_calidad' => $data->__GET('registro_calidad'),
                                    ':calidad_code' => $data->__GET('calidad_code'),
                                    ':cod_tempo' => $data->__GET('cod_tempo')
                                )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// ##############################################################################################

public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tipodocumentos (acro_documento,acro_subcategoria,tipo_documento,registro_calidad,calidad_code,cod_tempo)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
                ->execute(
                        array(
                            $data->__GET('acro_documento'),
                            $data->__GET('acro_subcategoria'),
                            $data->__GET('tipo_documento'),
                            $data->__GET('registro_calidad'),
                            $data->__GET('calidad_code'),
                            $data->__GET('cod_tempo')
                        )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

alumno.entidad2.php

```
<?php
class Categoria
{
private $acro_documento;
private $acro_subcategoria;
    private $tipo_documento;
    private $registro_calidad;
    private $calidad_code;
    private $cod_tempo;

public function __GET($k){ return $this->$k; }
public function __SET($k, $v){ return $this->$k = $v; }
}

</a>
```

O esta otra con la que tambien esoty probando

```
<a href="index2.php?action=editar&id&id="<?php echo $r->acro_documento; ?>
                                <?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/>
                            </a>
```

Se supone que recogen dos datos dados los cuales recoge pero no sabe redireccionarse o algo digo

el error de mysql y esta hecho en PDO

Comment: El error que recibes es de SQL (¿MySQL?) pero el código que compartes es PHP/HTML. Deberías compartir el código relevante al error.

Comment: En algunas de las sentencias SQL no tienes variables o tienes menos de las que estás intentando asociar (y parece que ese es el mensaje de error que te está dando). Prueba a solamente asociar las variables que se van a usar en cada sentencia, a ver si eso soluciona el problema.

Comment: En que parte no tengo variables? si tengo el mismo codigo cais para otro que unicamente tiene una PK y me funciona a la perfeccion :S Llevo hoy ya tantas horas que no se ni por donde me vienen los fallos si te digo la verdad xD!

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte del código tienes dos variables, pero sólo asocias una:

```
...

public function Obtener($acronimo) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento  = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
        $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $alm = new Categoria();

        ...
```

Eso es lo que puede estar lanzándote el error y lo mismo ocurre en la función `Eliminar` (puede estar ocurriendo en otras partes, pero al menos en esas dos).

Answer (score 0):

Pero en DELETE y en ese SELECT al menos en DELETE necesito seleccionar esos dos basicamente por que debo de eliminar de una BBDD registros que esta tiene dos primary key, entonces para eliminar un dato necesito seleccionar las dos Primary Key no se si me entiendes

En function eliminar hice este cambio

```
public function Eliminar($acro_documetno,$acro_subcategoria) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo
                ->prepare("DELETE FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acro_documento,$acro_subcategoria));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Ahora no lanza ningun error pero tampoco funciona

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function Eliminar($acro_documento,$acro_subcategoria) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo
                ->prepare("DELETE FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acro_documento,$acro_subcategoria));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Obtener($acro_documento,$acro_subcategoria) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento  = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acro_documento,$acro_subcategoria));
        $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $alm = new Categoria();

        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $r->acro_documento);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $r->acro_subcategoria);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $r->tipo_documento);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $r->registro_calidad);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $r->calidad_code);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $r->cod_tempo);

        return $alm;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y en el index

```
 <td>
                            <a href="index2.php?action=editar&id=;editar&id="<?php echo $r->acro_documento; ?><?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>>
                                 <img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/>
                            </a>                               

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=eliminar&acro_documento+acro_subcategoria=<?php echo $r->acro_documento; ?>
                                <?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height=30px"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
```

Asi lo tengo en estos momentos